# How to express the concept of negation in mathematics

Tags: mathematics, programming

I have been reading the PHP manual in both Japanese and English and have reached the part about operators.
In the `代数演算子` section they talk about `加算`, `減算` etc, and have a table showing all of the `代数演算子` (you can see it here: http://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

In the Japanese version of the manual they describe `-$a` as `負にする` but in the English version they use the word `Negation`.

I wondered if there was a noun in Japanese to describe this, like there is `加算` to describe `Addition`.

Since they use the word `Negation` in the English version I thought maybe `否定` in Japanese, but I'm not sure, so if any one knows of a noun to describe this concept any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, codecademy has some basic courses in Japanese that might be useful for seeing basic concepts explained as they would be to a native speaker.

Comment: @ssb Thank you for letting me know, I'll have to take a look at them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find here http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/negation

> 4)〔数学〕否定, 相反《真偽を逆にした命題》.

Comment: Thank you for linking me to this definition.
Just for everyone else's information, I found that the word for the - operator in Japanese when used as -$a is 単項マイナス演算子 (Unary Minus Operator).